# Windows 10 IOT core VPNClient

Tags: windows-iot, vpn

I have a little question.

Has Windows 10 IoT Core a VPN client or gives it as an app.

I will connect the raspberry to a external network.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 IOT running on the rpi isn't intended to be a general purpose client operating system.
The idea is to develop a program, send it to the rpi and the program runs.  Windows 10 IOT is designed as a single-use operating system. (IE an IOT device)
In this sense it is not as flexible as Rasberian since that opsys allows normal gui user activities.